# Find the maximum length of every column in a csv file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

So, I was trying to present a csv document in a console application. However, due to the varying text size in it, the output was not in a presentable format.

To present it, I tried to count the maximum length of text for each column and then append white space to the remaining text in that column so that there's equal length of characters in each column.

I tried to get the character count, but can't seem to figure out how to proceed further.

```
var file = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\File.csv");
var lineList = file.Select(x => x.Split(',').ToList()).ToList();
int maxColumn = lineList.Select(x => x.Count).Max(x => x);
List<int> maxElementSize = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < maxColumn; i++)
{
    //Some Logic    
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Splitting CSV by `','` is somewhat naïve, because a value might be a quoted string that contains a comma. If you don't want to waste time later, use an existing, proven library to parse your CSV.

Comment: If column A has maximum of 12 characters and column B has maximum of 14, do you want column A padded to 12 characters and B padded to 14?

Comment: @spender Do you have any existing library in mind that can help me achieve that?

Comment: @mjwills That's basically what I'm trying to achieve. Maximum column length for every column.

Comment: I've heard good things about [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a nested for loop:

```
var inputLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\File.csv");   
Dictionary<int,int> dictIndexLenght = new Dictionary<int,int>();
foreach(var line in inputLines)
{
    List<string> columList =  line.Split(',').ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < columList.Count; i++)
    {
        int tempVal = 0;
        if(dictIndexLenght.TryGetValue(i,out tempVal))
        {
            if(tempVal<columList[i].Length)
            {
                dictIndexLenght[i]=columList[i].Length;
            }                  
        }
        else
            dictIndexLenght[i]=columList[i].Length;
    }

}
```

Can check the result [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hynywD) or with this lines of code:

```
for(int i=0;i<dictIndexLenght.Count;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Column {0} : {1}", i, dictIndexLenght[i]);
}
```

Comment: @RufusL: thanks for pointing, that was bonus for copying `File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\File.csv");` from the question. Anyway updated the answer by removing that line, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample console application to get maximum character length for each column :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string CSVPath = @"D:\test.csv";
    string outputText = "";

    using (var reader = File.OpenText(CSVPath))
    {
        outputText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var colSplitter = ',';
    var rowSplitter = new char[] { '\n' };

    var rows = (from row in outputText.Split(rowSplitter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             let cols = row.Split(colSplitter)
             from col in cols
             select new { totalCols = cols.Count(), cols = cols }).ToList();

    int[] maxColLengths = new int[rows.Max(o => o.totalCols)];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows[i].cols.Count(); j++)
        {
            int curLength = rows[i].cols[j].Trim().Length;

            if (curLength  > maxColLengths[j])
                maxColLengths[j] = curLength;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", maxColLengths));
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, why do you think so? I have added it to remove empty rows which are usually present at the end of csv files.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I read that as part of the other (column) split - the way it is if fine, I just misread that.

Comment: This is also counting the double quotes of a field if it has any. Though CSV is not a strictly defined format. The "solution" should say that it does not care for quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it, very similar to un-lucky's answer, only using a `List<int>` instead of a `Dictionary<int, int>`. I added dummy data for testing, but you can see the actual call to read the file is left in there, so you can just remove the dummy data and the line that reads it, and it should work ok:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileLines = new List<string>
    {
        "Lorem, Ipsum, is, simply, dummy, text, of, the, printing, and, typesetting,",
        "industry., Lorem, Ipsum, has, been, the, industry's, standard, dummy, text,",
        "ever, since, the, 1500s, when, an, ",
        "unknown, printer, took, a, galley, of, type, and, scrambled, it, to, make,",
        "a, type, specimen, book.,",
        "It, has, survived, not, only, five, centuries, but, also, the, leap,",
        "into, electronic, typesetting, remaining, essentially, unchanged.,",
        "It, was, popularised, in, the, 1960s, with, the, release,",
        "of, Letraset, sheets, containing, Lorem, Ipsum, passages, and, more, ",
        "recently, with, desktop, publishing,",
        "software, like, Aldus, PageMaker, including, versions, of, Lorem, Ipsum."
    };

    var filePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.csv";
    var fileLinesColumns = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Select(line => line.Split(','));
    var colWidths = new List<int>();

    // Remove this line to use file data
    fileLinesColumns = fileLines.Select(line => line.Split(','));   

    // Get the max length of each column and add it to our list
    foreach (var fileLineColumns in fileLinesColumns)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileLineColumns.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i > colWidths.Count - 1)
            {
                colWidths.Add(fileLineColumns[i].Length);
            }
            else if (fileLineColumns[i].Length > colWidths[i])
            {
                colWidths[i] = fileLineColumns[i].Length;
            }
        }
    }

    // Write out our columns, padding each one to match the longest line
    foreach (var fileLineColumns in fileLinesColumns)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileLineColumns.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(fileLineColumns[i].PadRight(colWidths[i]));
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your list, then loop over your lines, and within that line, loop over your columns:

```
for (i = 0; i < lineList.Count; i++)
{
    maxElementSize[i] = 0;
}
for (i = 0; i < lineList.Count; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < maxColumn; j++)
    {
        if(lineList[i][j].Length > maxElementSize[j])
           maxElementSize[j] = lineList[i][j].Length
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a check if the row has a Length of more than `j` to avoid an `IndexOutOfRangeException` with jagged arrays.

Comment: It seems odd to set `maxElementSize[i]` for each **line** at the start (rather than for each **column**).

Comment: @mjwills I don't do that. Just because I re-used a variable name, that doesn't mean `i` means row... MaxElementSize is one-dimensional (so only has the columns) whereas lineList has rows and columns.

Answer (score -1):

I use the following code to make sure the columns in a database are large enough to take the csv input data...

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3 

    import array as arr
    from csv import reader
    import argparse
    
    
    def csv_getFldLens (in_file, has_header=0, delimiter=','):
        # open file in read mode
        fldMaxLens = arr.array('i')
        headers = []
        has_header = has_header
        with open(in_file, 'r') as read_obj:
            # pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
            csv_reader = reader(read_obj, delimiter=delimiter)
            # Iterate over each row in the csv using reader object
            rcnt = 0
            lastIndx = 0
            for row in csv_reader:
                # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
                # print(row)
                if has_header and rcnt == 0:
                    for fld in row:
                        headers.append(fld)
                    rcnt += 1
                    continue
    
                j = 0
                for fld in row:
                    fldLen = len(fld)
                    if (lastIndx == 0) or (lastIndx < j):
                        # print("if --- li, i: ",  lastIndx, i, "\n")
                        fldMaxLens.append(fldLen)
                        lastIndx = j
                    else:
                        # print("else --- li, i: ",  lastIndx, i, "\n")
                        v1 = fldMaxLens[j]
                        v2 = fldLen
                        fldMaxLens[j] = max(v1,v2)
                    j = j + 1
            rcnt += 1
        
    
        j = 0
        if has_header:
            for f in headers:
                print(f,": ", fldMaxLens[j])
                j += 1
        else:
            for i in fldMaxLens:
                print("Col[",j+1,"]: ",fldMaxLens[j])
                j += 1
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get column lengths of CVS fields.')
        parser.add_argument('--in_file', default='', help='The CSV input file')
        parser.add_argument('--has_header', action='store_true', help='The CSV file has headers')
        parser.add_argument('--delimiter', default=',', help='Sets the delimiter. Default is comma \',\'.')
        args = parser.parse_args()
    
        csv_getFldLens(in_file=args.in_file, has_header=args.has_header, delimiter=args.delimiter)
```

Comment: You've provided a python solution to a .Net question. Whilst your solution may work, it will not be immediately consumable in OP's environment. At the very least you should add a disclaimer acknowledging this and include implementation detail, so an example of how to compile and launch your function.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.